# Terraform API Gateway for use with Lambda Proxy Integration

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I've spent the day fighting with API Gateway and [AWS Serverless Express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express) to no avail. My goal is to deploy an API Gateway, via Terraform (v0.12), that [proxies all requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) to an AWS Serverless Express based lambda. The connection between API Gateway and Lambda seems to exist, but tenuous, as any invocation (from API Gateway console or Postman) respond with 502 Bad Gateway, apparently due to timeout (so states the lambda CloudWatch logs). It does not appear that the lambda code actually runs, only that it spins up ineffectually.

The API Gateway and Lambda should support path parameters and query strings:

1. `GET /some/path/:id` get by id
2. `GET /some/path?query=param` get
   collection
3. `POST /some/path` create resource
4. `PATCH /some/path/:id` update resource
5. `DELETE /some/path/:id` remove resource

After several false starts, I've tried to make the API Gateway Terraform module as flexible as possible:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "rest_api" {
  name        = "${var.application_name} API"
  description = var.description
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "proxy" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.root_resource_id # aws_api_gateway_resource.version.id
  path_part   = "{proxy+}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.id
  http_method   = "ANY"
  authorization = "NONE"

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.path.proxy" = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${local.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${var.lambda_arn}/invocations"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "apig_deployment" {
  depends_on = [
    "aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy",
    "aws_api_gateway_method.method",
    "aws_api_gateway_integration.integration"
  ]

  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  stage_name  = var.api_stage_name

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apig_to_lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = var.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:execute-api:${local.region}:${local.account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}/*/*/*" # TODO: lock this down
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 502 error that indicates that the response received by api gateway is not proper.

Having said that your application seems to return `json` response. Can you try  below/confirm the settings?

1. Add the correct binary mime types in your lambda configuration. See [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/blob/master/examples/basic-starter/lambda.js) for more details.
2. Allow the same mime types or wildcard on api gateway side as below.

```
    resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "rest_api" {
      name        = "${var.application_name} API"
      description = var.description

       // Wildcard mimes, accept any
      binary_media_types = ["*/*"]
    }
```

Comment: I gave this a go, but still timing out.